# Why does samtools mpileup sometimes include ref bases (other than ',' or '.')?

Tags: python, samtools, long-reads, mpileup

This is my first post here. I can think of no way of giving an easily reproducible example, as per the stack ethos. SO apologies in advance and any feedback on question format appreciated.

I have called samtools mpileup (Version: 1.9 (using htslib 1.9)) on some oxford nanopore data (mapped to GRCh38).

I am seeing some instances like below (grouped with pythons Counter), here reference is T at this position:

```
 Counter({',': 34, '.': 33, 'c': 9, 'g': 6, 'a': 4, 't': 2, '-:ACTC': 1, '-:ACTCGG': 1, '-:5': 1, '$': 1, '*': 1})
```

Why is 't': 2' in there?

flags used: -A -B -Q 1 -R -x

Comment: Hi Liam, can you show the exact mpileup for this position? Because I see that you tried to parse this into python and also converted the cases (no upper cases).

Comment: This way it's easier to see exactly was called.

Comment: Thanks @StupidWolf . I stupidly didn't keep the position of the above and it was just one example of a big list. So I'll edit above and give more examples and more details. I appreciate the help. At this point I'm thinking mpileup is a bit buggy, hoping that its resolvable.

Answer (score -1):

> Why is 't': 2' in there?

How else do you think the pileup should show you that two reads (in the reverse direction) have a T in that position?

Comment: Hey.. the reference is T, so if there are two bases with T on the reverse strand, it should be 2 ","

Comment: Yeah, that was the main point.